# Fortify on Oracle codebase

Tags: oracle, fortify

Fortify SCA behaviour for oracle codebase ( .sql , .trig , .pkg, .syn etc files) is not as expected :

Observations :
1) It reports Zero issues with Oracle codebase(s).
2) It considers only .sql files but not any other .pkg etc. Though introducing com.fortify.sca.fileextensions.pkg = PLSQL  in fortify-sca.properties dint help. It still doesnt consider .pkg files. Is there any other step required to achieve this? 
3) Though introducing SQL-injeciton code ( https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E38689_01/pt853pbr0/eng/pt/tpcd/task_PreventingSQLInjection-0749b7.html ) for testing purpose , also dint help. It doesnt catch this problem as well.

Are these known issues ?

Can someone please advise.

Answer (score 0):

By default, files with the extension *sql* are assumed to be T-SQL rather than PL/SQL on Windows platforms. If you are using Windows and have PL/SQL files with the sql extension, you can configure SCA to treat them as PL/SQL rather than explicitly specify it each time your run sourceanalyzer.
To change the default behavior, set the ***com.fortify.sca.fileextensions.sql*** property in fortify-sca.properties to “***TSQL***” or “***PLSQL***.”

Comment: Venu - SQL files are already considered but it doesnt recognize other extensions as .syn, .trig and .pkg etc. I am not specifying explicitly anywhere . I am launching Audit Workbench for scanning. In very first window , it shows packages , synonyms and triggers folders grey ( not recognized) . Even changing above property as above dint help.

Comment: Venu - Same results even after using command-lines.  Not sure , if Fortify SCA is expected to work on .trig , .syn extensions ( by including such extentions in fortify-sca.properties file : though adding them explicitly there doesnt help , those extensions still remain unrecognized ) . Its working very well for .pkb , .pks , .sql extensions.

Comment: Vishal- Can i know which version of Fortify you are using ?